# Select checkbox when clicking on the <tr> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've the following HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="elements_ids">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How with jQuery I can checked the checkbox if I click on the `<tr>` but only if this `<tr>` got a checkbox to check. I do not want this code affects all my table on my page.

I tried:

```
$(".table tbody tr").has(':checkbox').change(function(e){
    alert('ee');
});
```

Additionally, how can I revert this if the checkbox is checked ?

Could you please help ?

Comment: If I understand your question, your want that when a user click on a `tr`, it will check all the `checkboxes` inside this `tr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the checkbox in `tr` in the click event of it and then set checkbox status using `prop()` method like following.

```js
$(".table tbody tr").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) return; //ignore when click on the checkbox
  
    var $cb = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $cb.prop('checked', !$cb.is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="elements_ids">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works. I just forgot to ask ho to revert the check by clicking again on the row please ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cotsk06f/2/)

And the javascript for what you need:

```
$("tr").on("click", function(e){
    $("input[type='checkbox']", this).each( function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

This way it will invert all the checkboxes on the clicked row.